# Acting irresponsibly

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I can't manage to find a word or phrase that will describe the **process of putting off/taking off the responsibility from oneself**.

Comment: Putting off is procrastination, the other might be irresponsibility.

Comment: Is it correct to say PROCRASTINATE RESPONSIBILITY?

Comment: One may "duck/avoid his responsibilities", "shirk/evade responsibility", "run away/shy away/escape from his responsibilities"

Comment: I absolutely wouldn't say it's correct or valid in any shape or form. Procastrination is an action in itself, about something - it doesn't carry a subject though, and it'd be mostly alien to any English spoken/written by any user.

Comment: Please provide more information. See these links: [1](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info), [2](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7699/what-is-wrong-with-my-question?cb=1).

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. The following is the rule of this community. **Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered**. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Shirk" implies deceitful avoidance. But falls short of evasion.

> 1630s, "to practice fraud or trickery," also a noun (1630s, now
>   obsolete) "a needy, disreputable parasite" [OED], perhaps from German
>   schurke "scoundrel, rogue, knave, villain" (see shark (n.)). Sense of
>   "evade one's work or duty" first recorded 1785, originally in slang.
>   Related: Shirked ; shirking.

Evasion implies an active effort to "skirt" a responsibility.

> 13. to avoid, go around the edge of, or keep distant from (something that is controversial, risky, etc.): The senator skirted the issue.

"Abnegation" is lacking in deceit.

> 1. to refuse or deny oneself (some rights, conveniences, etc.); reject; renounce.

Dictionary.com.

less commonly, derogate.

> 3 [NO OBJECT] (derogate from) Deviate from (a set of rules or agreed
>   form of behavior): one country has derogated from the Rome Convention

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/derogate

Answer (score 2):

**pass the buck**

> to blame someone or to make them responsible for a problem that you should deal with yourself
>
> Usage notes: In the card game poker, the buck is an object passed to the person who wins in order to remind them that they must be the first person to give money for the prize in the next game.
>
> (sometimes + to ) *Parents often try to pass the buck to teachers when children misbehave in school. Bus companies are just passing the buck by saying their drivers are responsible for delays.*

.

> Fig. to pass the blame (to someone else); to give the responsibility (to someone else). (See also The buck stops here.) *Don't try to pass the buck! It's your fault, and everybody knows it. Some people try to pass the buck whenever they can.*

-- http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pass+the+buck

Answer (score 0):

- Unliable,
- Unblaming(haven't seen that... in ages. A really old form of not blaming/unsuspected/not faulted)
- Acting(! This would be the perfect example, except it's universal.)
- Decieve
- Feigning (innocence)
- Other synonyms about negative/malicious intent + acting

I don't really think there's an exact, perfectly situational, fitting one-word expression for this.

Answer (score 0):

- **devil-may-care** (adj) - Carefree, reckless, irresponsible.
- **faineant** (n) - An irresponsible or lazy person.
- **flibbertigibbet** (n) - A flighty person; someone regarded as silly , irresponsible , or scatterbrained , especially someone who chatters or gossips.
- **freewheeler** (n) - Someone acting freely or even irresponsibly.
- **faineant** (adj) - Wildly, carelessly, irresponsibly. (also a noun)
- **slaphappy** (adj) - Irresponsibly free.